# C# ReadProcessMemory AccessViolationException in WinForms but not in Console

Tags: c#, winforms, access-violation, readprocessmemory

I'm writing a program which reads and writes the memory of a process. For testing purposes I wrote it first in a console application, which works; but when I moved on to a WinForms/WPF application, I get a AccessViolationException when using ReadProcessMemory from kernel32.dll.

My code:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr Handle, long Address, byte[] buffer, int Size, int BytesRead = 0);

    ReadProcessMemory(GetProcessHandle(), Pointer, Buffer, Buffer.Length);
```

Why do I only get the AccessViolationException in WinForms/WPF but not in a console application, and how do I bypass this in WinForms? The error itself gives very little information to what's causing it.

Comment: Bad declaration, the likely difference in behavior is that one is built to target 32-bit code execution and the other 64-bit execution.  The target you pick should match the bitness of the process you're trying to manipulate.  Address is an IntPtr.  BytesRead must be `out IntPtr` to be functional.  If you intend to pass NULL, as suggested, then make it plain IntPtr and pass IntPtr.Zero.

Comment: Where did you get this declaration from? Copy the first [ReadProcessMemory](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.readprocessmemory) declaration from PInvoke.NET -- Target AnyCPU and see that you don't have `Prefer-32bit` ticked.

Comment: @HansPassant That's it, Winforms ran as 32-bit but was trying to access a 64-bit program. Got it working now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using [`Marshal.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=net-6.0#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-copy(system-intptr-system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32))?